# Django URLresolver, optional value

Tags: django, django-urls

In my urls.py file, I currently have the following resolver :

```
url(r'$', 'methodology_home')
url(r'^(?P<methodology_type\w+)/$', 'methodology_home')
```

I'd like the merge the two by saying that methodology_type is optional (and by specifying an argument with a default value in my view).
Is it feasible by simply adding a ? in the regexp ? I thought so at first but I was unable to make it work.

Does someone has an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I think the urls.py is clearer if you **don't** merge the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regex to catch an [optional url paramater](https://gist.github.com/c4urself/1028897)

```
url(r'^(?:(?P<methodology_type>\w+)/?)?$', 'methodology_home')
```

One issue with this approach, though, is that your view will get `None` if no parameter is given. That's because the regex will in fact match and the value of the group is `None`:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:(?P<methodology_type>\w+)/?)?$')
pattern.match('foo').groupdict()
>>> {'methodology_type': 'foo'}

pattern.match('').groupdict()
>>> {'methodology_type': None}
```

So you either handle it in your view code:

```
def my_view(request, methodology_type):
    methodology_type = methodology_type or 'default'
    ...
```

or you stick with the two separated rules you already have.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work, in my view : 

def methodology_home(request,methodology_type='default'):

If I leave it empty, methodology_type doesn't take the default value.

Comment: @user1058398 and what does it take instead?

Comment: It takes "None", it doesn't consider as if I didn't specify the argument (and does not take the default value then).